# Is Blender building the wrong strips into Proxies

Tags: video-sequence-editor, timeline, proxies

I have a small strip I'm trying to build into a proxy, so I can go through and find all the frames I want to lay pictures and text over my videos. However, I try to make a proxy with 1 minute and 20 seconds of video at 50% and it says 1 hour to complete. AM I doing something horribly wrong that is resulting in my entire 3 hours of the movie being proxied? I only want this tiny clip to be built as a proxy. please help.

Comment: What steps did you take to build the proxies?

Comment: I selected the strips, flagged them for proxy, selected the 2 qualities i wanted, then selected "Rebuild Proxies"